# Stripline title show on top of stripline instead of bottom of it

Tags: vb.net

I need the title just like this image, right now the title is locate at bottom of the stripline in my project.

http://support2.dundas.com/Articles/792/image002.jpg

Comment: Additional information would be helpful, what chart library are you using? Do you have any sample code?

Comment: @Bond i using vb2013

Comment: @JoelLegaspiEnriquez the stripline code is working prefectly, i just want to know is there any method to move the stripline title on top of the line. I using vb2013.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using MSChart, set the TextLineAlignment property:

```
strip.TextLineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;
```

Comment: The text still remain under the stripline. Thank for your reply.

Comment: Perhaps there is an orientation issue. This worked for me. Have you tried the other StringAlignment values?